# Firefox keeps dying on me

Tags: firefox

I've got a bit weird problem.
it's been a while that Firefox keeps dying. I mean it's not crashed, everything is working fine, I can do all things like opening and closing tabs and use many plugins. The only problem is, it does not load any and I mean absolutely any page, no matter if I click on a link or click on my bookmarks or even manually enter the address.
It keeps staying in the `Connecting` state for a minute or two and then gets working again.
It happens every now and then but mostly when I have just opened the browser.

It's been like this from Firefox 5 to version 9 (latest)!

**NOTE:** I'm using Ubuntu (oneiric).

Comment: Does this occur on other browsers on your computer?

Comment: I have to say that I have had so many problems with FF that I have switched back to Chrome. I had problems EVERY time FF updated and finally it crashed completely.

Comment: @music2myear Nope, everything is fine with them.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Ahhh, the old debate about browsers. In my opinion FF with all it's problem is a far better browser that Chrome will ever be.

Comment: Do the troublesome pages open when you use their IP address instead of a name?  Have you tried changing DNS servers? When it won't load a page does it just hang, or do you get any error messages/pages?

Comment: @techie007 Haven't tried to use their IP. But even the `localhost` dose not load. And it just hangs, no errors.

Comment: Does this problem occur which a different user account on the same system? Have you tried using a different Firefox profile?

Comment: @DanielBeck No, I haven't tried that. I will.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling it and reinstalling it again.  I had these kind of problem before and reinstalling it fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case for me. even after reinstalling the whole OS the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to try:

- try accessing webpage by IP address for example: http://85.128.128.36
- is it possible that you have firewall? try to turn it off? maybe it's blocking firefox explicitly?
- try changing dns servers you are using (although reading comments mean other browsers are working fine so I guess dns servers should be fine too). Try to ping
- any addons ? disable them all or even start firefox in [Safe Mode](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode) or a more [Ubuntu way](http://ubuntu.igameilive.com/2010/05/how-to-run-firefox-in-safe-mode-in.html)
- does `telnet google.com 80` outside of browser (in shell) works ?
- check any `proxy settings` in Firefox, comparing to other browsers? or maybe other browsers are using Proxy that your network requires you to?